# Cannot get Azure Build Solution to use specific XML transformation file

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I cloned an existing Build pipeline, where everything is the same except the variable values, however the XML transformation is not happening correctly, it's transforming using the incorrect file.

The QA pipeline works successfully, and looks like the below:

Pipeline variables:

[image]

Build solution step:

[image]

Log file showing transformation with "QA", which is correct:

[image]

The Dev pipeline is the exact same as above, but with different variable values:

[image]

Issue is that it's picking up "debug" file instead of "dev" file:

[image]

All config files exist in the branch I am building:

[image]

Any idea why the Dev pipeline is using Web.Debug.config instead of Web.Dev.config file during build process?

Comment: Not sure why this not works for you, but it works for me.Did you just try hard-coding the value `DEV` in the `Configuration` field of your build pipeline instead of getting it from the variable ?

Comment: Which task you are using transform the XML file?

Comment: Your images don't show the scope of your variables. Make sure you check that they are set for QA and Dev appropriately and not Release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. The transformation is happening as part of the build solution step - in the solution file. The issue is that someone had changed the configuration in the solution file so that every config defaulted to "Debug", except for QA, which was set correctly.  Once I reverted that change, everything worked as expected.